# How to log terminal number in bash history?

Tags: bash, command-history, bashrc

We have more than one admin, and sometimes need to know from which pts the command was issued.

Now the history looks like:

```
998  2016-08-25 10:16:41 ls /usr/local/apache/htdocs/
```

Is there any way to add the pts number to each line so then the user can be checked via `last`?

Current bashrc (in part related to history)

```
# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend
# Don't save trivial one and two character commands on the history list
export HISTIGNORE="?:??:exit"
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%h %d %T "
export HISTCONTROL="ignoredups"
export HISTFILESIZE=20000
export HISTSIZE=20000
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
```

Comment: if you don't need the tty *in* the histfile, you could set HISTFILE to include the tty as part of the filename.

Comment: @JeffSchaller do you mean one file per terminal? It'll kill ability to search e.g. by ^R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the `export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%h %d %T "` and add the information of the filename of the terminal through the `tty` command, like

```
export TERMINAL=`tty | cut -d\/ -f4`
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="$TERMINAL %h %d %T "
```

Comment: It only shows the number of the current terminal but it is not useful because it should show the number of the terminal where the command was executed.