# How to set the history log properly?

Tags: bash, history

There are two lines in regular user .bashrc(debian8).

```
cat /home/debian8/.bashrc

export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T   `tty` "
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -w"
```

At the first  login with user debian8 and to input `tty` `pwd`,not to close it .
[image]

At the second login with user debian8 and to input `tty` `ls`.
[image]

Now to reboot pc and  get log info with history command.
What i get is as below:

```
debian8@hwy:~$ history
    1  2017-03-02 22:48:25   /dev/pts/0 tty
    2  2017-03-02 22:48:28   /dev/pts/0 pwd
    3  2017-03-02 22:48:38   /dev/pts/0 tty
    4  2017-03-02 22:48:40   /dev/pts/0 ls
    5  2017-03-02 22:48:38   /dev/pts/0 tty
    6  2017-03-02 22:48:40   /dev/pts/0 ls
    7  2017-03-02 22:48:25   /dev/pts/0 tty
    8  2017-03-02 22:48:28   /dev/pts/0 pwd
    9  2017-03-02 22:48:55   /dev/pts/0 history
```

Why can't get the info such as following?How to get the following log info?

```
debian8@hwy:~$ history
    1  2017-03-02 22:48:25   /dev/pts/0 tty
    2  2017-03-02 22:48:28   /dev/pts/0 pwd
    3  2017-03-02 22:48:38   /dev/pts/1 tty
    4  2017-03-02 22:48:40   /dev/pts/1 ls
    5  2017-03-02 22:48:55   /dev/pts/0 history
```

To change from

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T   `tty` "
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -w"
```

into

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T   `tty` "
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a"
```

not **'%F %T   `tty` '**.

What i get is

```
debian8@hwy:~$ history
    1  2017-03-02 22:48:25   /dev/pts/0 tty
    2  2017-03-02 22:48:28   /dev/pts/0 pwd
    3  2017-03-02 22:48:38   /dev/pts/0 tty
    4  2017-03-02 22:48:40   /dev/pts/0 ls
    5  2017-03-02 22:48:55   /dev/pts/0 history
```

Is there no way to get such info as following?

```
debian8@hwy:~$ history
    1  2017-03-02 22:48:25   /dev/pts/0 tty
    2  2017-03-02 22:48:28   /dev/pts/0 pwd
    3  2017-03-02 22:48:38   /dev/pts/1 tty
    4  2017-03-02 22:48:40   /dev/pts/1 ls
    5  2017-03-02 22:48:55   /dev/pts/0 history
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305734/how-to-log-terminal-number-in-bash-history/305739

Comment: The post `How to log terminal number in bash history?` can't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is an actual **workaround** by setting the `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable in `~/.bash_profile` or in `~/.bashrc` which creates an extra log.

The file `~/.bash_history` only keeps a timestamp and the command like this:

```
#1488631365
ls -lah
#1488631367
history
#1488631380
cat ~/.bash_history
```

the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` environment variable is only the setting how the `#1488631380` should be [translated/displayed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html).

---

The following would create todays logfile - `~/bash-history-2017-03-04.log`

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -e "$(tty)\t$(history 1)" >> ~/bash-history-$(date "+%Y-%m-%d").log'
```

example output (depending how `HISTTIMEFORMAT` is setup)

```
/dev/pts/1        541  [04/03 14:02:37] tty
/dev/pts/1        542  [04/03 14:02:45] echo "hi from tty1"
/dev/pts/0        523  [04/03 13:55:07] cat ~/.bash_history
/dev/pts/0        524  [04/03 14:02:53] tty
/dev/pts/0        525  [04/03 14:02:58] echo "hi from tty 0"
```